# Refresh Laravel environment variables on shared hosting

Tags: laravel, variables, refresh, environment

I implemented my website on a shared hosting environment. Works perfect!
But now I changed functionality and want to use 'queues'. In my earlier instance the environment variable 'queue_driver' contained the default value 'sync', and now I changed that to 'database' in the environment file.

Question is now: how to activate this new setting?

I already tried to clear cache and config, but it does not change anything?

Can I enforce refreshment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `php artisan config:clear` to clear the cached config files.

Maybe also follow up with `composer dumpautoload`

Comment: I already used the artisan clear config and cache.
Should I use the composer command via SSH ?

Comment: Don't run `php artisan config:cache` on your production server. Your code won't be able to read the .ENV variables. SSH into your server and run the 2 commands above only and nothing else.

Comment: A good way to test this is to SSH into your server and run `php artisan tinker` and then type `env("QUEUE_DRIVER")` and see what the output is

Comment: @user3574492 I don't think that statement 'Don't run `php artisan config:cache` on production server' is correct. In fact, its recommended as your config value is cached then your app can run faster without round trip to your `.env` file. What ever restricts you from using `config:cache` command in production may mean you're accessing your `.env` variable in your code, where you could have used `config` variables.

Comment: A quick way apart from what @user3574492 suggested would be to change the default driver in the config file to database. Well, its better if its from the `.env` but that's why it is there in config file so the default can be changed. That is, this line: `'default' => env('QUEUE_DRIVER', 'database'),` NB: This should be the last resort in case clearing cache doesn't work.

Comment: @OluwatobiSamuelOmisakin and what's wrong with accessing .ENV variables directly in code? Isn't that the whole point of it? Otherwise why have a .ENV file altogether then? Then why not just use the config files for storing all app keys?

Comment: @user3574492, the .env file should be used to contain sensitive information. The config files should be the only ones to reference the env values because they are cached. So if you need to reference an env value in your code, add a config file or add it to one of the existing ones if that makes sense. In your code, reference this config value instead.